# semaphore p3 blocked forever?

Tags: semaphore

I have the following code, and I want to know what `printf` prints:
 I did it, but I am not sure about my answer.

Variables: d=0, A=1,B=1, C=0.

```
p1               p2                  p3
while(1) {       while(1){           while(1){  
   P(A); P(B);      P(A); P(B);         P(C); P(C);
   d = 2*d;         d = d+1;            printf("%d\n",d);
   V(C)             V(C);               V(A); V(B);
}                }                   }
```

My try was:

`C=0, p3` is blocked
    starting form process

```
p1 A=0, B=0 and d=0 and C=1.
p2 blocks because A=0 and B=0, p3
```

It also blocks in the second `P(C)`. `A=0, B=0, C=0` happens a deadlock, and `printf` does not print anything. Is this correct?

Comment: For those of us that are not psychic or in your class, what does `P(X)` and `V(X)` do?

Comment: @Dukeling, `P` is traditionally `down`/`wait` and `V` is `up`/`signal`.

Comment: sorry, P(X) is down and V(X) is up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are right - deadlock - nothing printed.

at deadlock: p3 is waiting at second P(C). either p1 or p2 has done its first iteration, the other - zero iteration. both p1 and p2 is waiting at P(A). value of d depends on race between p1 and p2 - which entered first iteration.